# SQLite - using Count() to get row count - then use conditional

Tags: c#, android, sql, sqlite, xamarin

EDIT3:
I found the answer. I thank everyone for his help! It was kind of stupid, but everyone makes these mistakes sometimes, I guess.

Question:

I'm using Xamarin for Android and the Sqlite-net Nuget for SQL and have the following Code

```
    protected void settingTags() {

        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection (dbPath)) {

            var rowCount = connection.Table<User> ().Count ();

            if (rowCount <= 1) {
                // Setting the column "Person" of "Row where Primary Key is
                // "1" to the variable "person" in the table "User"

                // This gets the Row where the primary key attribute 
                // is "1"
                var presentUser = connection.Get<User> (1);

                // This sets the column "Persons" to "persons" where
                // person is an integer and is 1
                presentUser.Persons = persons;

                // This updates the Database
                connection.Update (presentUser);

                Log.Info (Tag, "User Data Updated");
            }
            else if (rowCount > 1) {
                for (int i = rowCount; i >= 1; i--) {
                    connection.Delete(new User(){ID=i});
                }
                settingTags ();
            }
        }
    }
```

This gives me an empty exception Error.
I used Breakpoints to pinpoint the error and somehow it is in the line:

```
            if (rowCount <= 1) {
```

And of course the other conditional.

Edit2:
But the actual error lies in the line:

```
            var presentUser = connection.Get<User> (1);
```

I used the code as it is used in the Documentation. 
And there is a row with the Primary Key "1" ...

I'd really appreciate any help.
And sorry if I used wrong tags or something like that for this question as this is my first. :s

Edit: rowCount is 6. So it has a value.

Comment: What is the value of rowCount if it is less than 1? What do you do if this condition is true?

Comment: Based on your debugging using breakpoints, what was the value of `rowCount` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. it is rowCount <= 1 - Well, I set the column "Persons" from the Row where the Primary Key is "1" to the variable "persons" (in the table "User"). Thank you I will edit my answer accordingly, Steve!
Cyval, rowCount is 6.

Comment: The debugger sometimes breaks on the line *after* the one with the error. So the call to `Count` could be failing.

Comment: Can you explain what this line means? _connection.Get<User> (1);_ What will happen if your rowCount is zero here? Could you add the exact spell of the error message received?

Comment: It gets a specific "row" out of the database. Here it is the row where the primary key is "1".

Comment: Can you include the error you receive?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I tried to use this method as a recursive method, but the for loop

```
            else if (rowCount > 1) {
                for (int i = rowCount; i >= 1; i--) {
                    connection.Delete(new User(){ID=i});
                }
                settingTags ();
            }
```

didn't delete the rows. So, hello infinity-loop. I changed the method as followed:

```
    protected void settingTags() {

        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection (dbPath)) {

            var rowCount = connection.Table<User> ().Count ();

            var presentUser = connection.Get<User> (1);

            Log.Info (Tag, "rowCount: " + rowCount.ToString ());

            if (rowCount > 1) {
                Log.Info (Tag, "Database cleared");
                for (int i = rowCount; i > 0-1; i--) {
                    //var del = connection.Delete<User> (i);
                    var deleted = connection.Query<User> ("DELETE FROM User WHERE ID = ?", i);
                    Log.Info (Tag, "for loop i: " + i.ToString ());
                    Log.Info (Tag, "Rows deleted: " + deleted.ToString ());
                }
            }

            rowCount = connection.Table<User> ().Count ();

            if (rowCount <= 1) {
                presentUser.Persons = persons;
                connection.Update (presentUser);
                //var Users = connection.Query<User>("UPDATE User SET Persons = ? WHERE ID = 1", persons);
                Log.Info (Tag, "User Data Updated");
            }

        }
    }
```

And it works now.
Thanks to all for trying to help me!

---